# Applying Jquery UI theme to Asp.net buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have an Asp.Net button and I am applying flick theme to my buttons and it's applying to it but on mouse hovering it doesn't change the colour.

Here is what I am doing?May be I am wrong Can anyone guide me through this as I am able to work with normal html button by using

```
<button>Click Me!</button>
```

This is how I am working with Asp.net button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me!" CssClass="ui-button ui-state-default"/>
```

Comment: jQuery UI's button doesn't work with `input type="submit"` or `input type="button"`, only the semantic `button` element.  If you only want to apply the styles, you can refer to an ASP.NET element by using the 'ends-in' selector: `$('input[id$="Button1"]')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I have changed by simple adding a script tag (#btnSample).button;And in the code view i have removed my CssClass and changed it to <asp:button ID="btnSample></asp:button> and got working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways I found the answer and here is what I have did and worked well!

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$('#btnSample').button();
</script>
```

Code for displaying:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSample" runat="server" Text="Click Me!"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

In ASP.NET the ID get's transformed so you can't pass it as a selector. You could probably use a class instead.

So instead of

```
$('#Button1').button();
```

use

```
$('.MyButtonStyle').button();
```

EDIT:

BTW, you shouldn't be adding any jquery-ui classes to the button manually (your example looks like that's what you are doing). This is all done by the .js file included with jquery ui

Comment: Thanks for your reply and actually still I couldn't get through your answer well I have changed in my script to $('MyButtonStyle').button; and Still I have the same problem.

Comment: I got it working and changed the code and will post the answer soon.

Comment: *If* you need to use the id in the selector for ASP controls do this: $('[id$=myButtonIDGoesHere]')

Answer (score 0):

try to set button property as

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

Then

Answer (score 0):

man its easy , just add the following and it will work just fine :

```
    $(function () {
      $("input[type=submit]").button();
    });
```